# Spark - Map flat dataframe to a configurable nested json schema

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, case-class

I have a flat dataframe with 5-6 columns. I want to nest them and convert it into a nested dataframe so that I can then write it to parquet format.

However, I don't want to use case classes as I am trying to keep the code as configurable as possible. I'm stuck with this part and need some help.

My Input :

```
ID ID-2 Count(apple) Count(banana) Count(potato) Count(Onion)

 1  23    1             0             2             0

 2  23    0             1             0             1

 2  29    1             0             1             0
```

My Output :

ROW 1 :

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "ID-2": 23,
  "fruits": {
    "count of apple": 1,
    "count of banana": 0
  },
  "vegetables": {
    "count of potato": 2,
    "count of onion": 0
  }
}
```

I have tried using the "map" function in the spark dataframe where I map my values to a case class. However, I will be playing around with the name of the fields and might change them too.

I dont want to maintain a case class and map rows to the sql column names as that would involve code changes everytime.

I was thinking of maintaining a Hashmap with the column names I want to keep with the column names of the dataframe. For instance, in the example, I'm mapping "Count(apple)" to "count of apple". However, I can't think of a nice easy way to pass my schema as a config and then map it in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach using the scala `Map` type to create column mappings using the following dataset:

```
val data = Seq(
(1, 23, 1, 0, 2, 0),
(2, 23, 0, 1, 0, 1),
(2, 29, 1, 0, 1, 0)).toDF("ID", "ID-2", "count(apple)", "count(banana)", "count(potato)", "count(onion)")
```

First we declare the mappings using `scala.collection.immutable.Map` collection and the function which is responsible for the mapping:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame}

val colMapping = Map(
        "count(banana)" -> "no of banana", 
        "count(apple)" -> "no of apples", 
        "count(potato)" -> "no of potatos", 
        "count(onion)" -> "no of onions")

def mapColumns(colsMapping: Map[String, String], df: DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
       val mapping = df
         .columns
         .map{ c => if (colsMapping.contains(c)) df(c).alias(colsMapping(c)) else df(c)}
         .toList

        df.select(mapping:_*)
}
```

The function iterates though the columns of the given dataframe and identify the columns that have common keys with the `mapping`. Then it returns the column changing its name (with alias) according to the applied mappings.

Output of `mapColumns(colMapping, df).show(false)`:

```
+---+----+------------+------------+-------------+------------+
|ID |ID-2|no of apples|no of banana|no of potatos|no of onions|
+---+----+------------+------------+-------------+------------+
|1  |23  |1           |0           |2            |0           |
|2  |23  |0           |1           |0            |1           |
|2  |29  |1           |0           |1            |0           |
+---+----+------------+------------+-------------+------------+
```

Finally we generate fruits and vegetables via `struct` type:

```
df1.withColumn("fruits", struct(col(colMapping("count(banana)")), col(colMapping("count(apple)"))))
.withColumn("vegetables", struct(col(colMapping("count(potato)")), col(colMapping("count(onion)"))))
.drop(colMapping.values.toList:_*)
.toJSON
.show(false)
```

Note that we drop all the cols of the colMapping collection after finishing with the transformations.

Output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"ID":1,"ID-2":23,"fruits":{"no of banana":0,"no of apples":1},"vegetables":{"no of potatos":2,"no of onions":0}}|
|{"ID":2,"ID-2":23,"fruits":{"no of banana":1,"no of apples":0},"vegetables":{"no of potatos":0,"no of onions":1}}|
|{"ID":2,"ID-2":29,"fruits":{"no of banana":0,"no of apples":1},"vegetables":{"no of potatos":1,"no of onions":0}}|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hello, this time I added the mapping functionality which was missing

Comment: Thanks you, I figured a way to do it by fitting it into my use case!

Comment: Good then I am glad

Answer (score 1):

```
val df = spark.sqlContext.read.option("header","true").csv("/sampleinput.txt")

val df1 = df.withColumn("fruits",struct("Count(apple)","Count(banana)") ).withColumn("vegetables",struct("Count(potato)","Count(Onion)")).groupBy("ID","ID-2").agg(collect_list("fruits") as "fruits",collect_list("vegetables") as "vegetables").toJSON 

df1.take(1)
```

Output:

```
{"ID":"2","ID-2":"23","fruits":[{"Count(apple)":"0","Count(banana)":"1"}],"vegetables":[{"Count(potato)":"0","Count(Onion)":"1"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

:: (double colon) in scala is treated as "cons" in scala lists.
This is the way of creating a scala List or inserting an element to an existing mutable list.

```
scala> val aList = 24 :: 34 :: 56 :: Nil
aList: List[Int] = List(24, 34, 56)

scala> 99 :: aList
res3: List[Int] = List(99, 24, 34, 56)
```

In first example Nil is the empty list , and considered as the tail for the rightmost cons operation.

However

```
scala> val anotherList = 23 :: 34
<console>:12: error: value :: is not a member of Int
       val anotherList = 23 :: 34
```

This throws an error because there is no existing list to insert in.